# How to get a file location url from a php redirect link?

Tags: php, firefox, wget

I have a link to a download to a file that calls a php script before it starts downloading the file. Is it possible to somehow get the location of the file that is to be downloaded directly (maybe through some browser plugin)?

I need this because I want to use wget on another system to download the file directly. A problem might be authentication because I need to provide a username and password, but getting the file location URL is the first step I think.

Thanks,

Ivan

Comment: You may do it by using CURL and CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER option as far as I remember.

Answer (score 3):

If the PHP script directly reads the file, no, you will never get the real location of that file.

If it redirects to it, yes, it's possible using the Firebug "net" tab or Live HTTP headers extension.